# Infopath Designer 2013 - SharePoint form Date validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I am creating a sharepoint list for by infopath designer 2013.

I have three dates fields

1. Start Date
2. Last Actioned Date
3. Completion Date

Condition i want to apply

1. Start date should not be future date. (which has been done by now() function)
2. last actioned date should be equal to and more that Start date and equal to and less than to completion date
3. completion date should not be less than last actioned date or start date

need help

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps for your reference:

Rule and ScreenTip for Start Date:
[image]
Rule and ScreenTip for Last Actioned Date:

[image]

Rule and ScreenTip for Completion Date:

[image]
Result:
[image]